Animating pixels in GDI
I am trying to animate a rainbow color effect in GDI, so far I have created a static rainbow that doesn't animate.
My approach to animate it was that I should shift the array elements to the next position like [0,1,2] becomes [2,0,1] and call setpixelv() again. But I think its time consuming and inefficient.
Here is my actual code:
#include <windows.h>

const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 600;
const int BAR_WIDTH = 600;
const int BAR_HEIGHT = 50;

int imageData[498 * 1] = {0xFB017D, 0xFB0278, 0xFB017D, 0xFC0280, 0xFB027A, 0xFB027A, 0xFB017C, 0xFA0175, 0xFC026E, 0xFC026C, 0xFC036B, 0xFC0266,
                          0xFC0263, 0xFC015E, 0xFC025B, 0xFB015A, 0xFB0351, 0xFB0351, 0xFC014E, 0xFC024C, 0xFC0249, 0xFC0146, 0xFC0242, 0xFC0241, 0xFD0237, 0xFD0237, 0xFD0237, 0xFD0235, 0xFD0132, 0xFD022D, 0xFD0329, 0xFC0226, 0xFC0228, 0xFC0323, 0xFC021D, 0xFC0319, 0xFE0219, 0xFD0116, 0xFD0213, 0xFC020E, 0xFC020C, 0xFC030B, 0xFB0206, 0xFB0304, 0xFB0303, 0xF90403, 0xF90304, 0xF90306, 0xFD0002, 0xFE0606, 0xFB0905, 0xF90C04, 0xFC1005, 0xFD1104, 0xFB1404, 0xFC1906, 0xF81A03, 0xFB2004, 0xFB2203, 0xFA2402, 0xFA2805, 0xF82A05, 0xF82D04, 0xFB3204, 0xFB3705, 0xF93A06, 0xFA3D06, 0xFC3F05, 0xFF4105, 0xFE4203, 0xFC4604, 0xFB4A06, 0xFB5106, 0xFC5207, 0xFB5406, 0xFC5707, 0xFB5904, 0xFB5B03, 0xFC5D02, 0xFC5E03, 0xFC6303, 0xFB6504, 0xFC6804, 0xFB6E04, 0xFC7205, 0xFC7605, 0xFC7905, 0xFD7A04, 0xF97B02, 0xFC7E03, 0xFB8102, 0xFB8402, 0xFC8A05, 0xFC8C04, 0xFA8F03, 0xFD9204, 0xFB9703, 0xFC9804, 0xFC9A03, 0xFC9D03, 0xFBA103, 0xFCA603, 0xFDAA06, 0xFEAD06, 0xFBAE06, 0xFDB306, 0xFDB805, 0xFCBC05, 0xFBBD06, 0xFAC005, 0xFCC304, 0xFEC502, 0xFACC05, 0xFBCD05, 0xFBD007, 0xFDD305, 0xFAD403, 0xFAD703, 0xF9DA03, 0xFBDC05, 0xFDE104, 0xFAE202, 0xF8E703, 0xFBED06, 0xFDEF06, 0xFCEE05, 0xFAF005, 0xFAF307, 0xFAF503, 0xF8F603, 0xF7F605, 0xF2F504, 0xF0F505, 0xEDF605, 0xECF703, 0xEBF904, 0xE6FC06, 0xE1F903, 0xDDF904, 0xDCFC05, 0xD7FB05, 0xD4FC06, 0xD3FB05, 0xCEF801, 0xCEF703, 0xCCF803, 0xC8FA05, 0xC2FA03, 0xBEFA04, 0xBAFA05, 0xB6FB04, 0xB3F902, 0xB4FA04, 0xB3F903, 0xB0FA03, 0xADFB05, 0xAAFC06,
                          0xA2FA05, 0x9EF904, 0x9CFB07, 0x98FA05, 0x94F802, 0x92F703, 0x8FF903, 0x8DFB06, 0x89FB06, 0x84FA04, 0x82FA03, 0x83FB06, 0x7DF905, 0x77F905, 0x77FA06, 0x77FA08, 0x73F906, 0x6EFA03, 0x6AFB02, 0x6AFA04, 0x68F802, 0x68FA04, 0x63F904, 0x5DF703, 0x58F804, 0x56FA05, 0x52FA04, 0x53F903, 0x4DF903, 0x4AFA04, 0x47F905, 0x47F905, 0x45F806, 0x3FF902, 0x3BF901, 0x3BFC05, 0x36FA02, 0x32F803, 0x2EF804, 0x2CF906, 0x27F904, 0x27F904, 0x26FA05, 0x1FFB03, 0x1CFB04, 0x18FA03, 0x14FA04, 0x10FA05, 0x0CFA04, 0x0CFA04, 0x0BFB04, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x04F904, 0x03FA0B, 0x03FA0B, 0x03FA0D, 0x04FA0F, 0x04FA13, 0x03FA15, 0x04FA19, 0x04FA1B, 0x02F922, 0x03FA23, 0x03FA27, 0x03F92A, 0x04F92F, 0x05FA33, 0x04FA37, 0x04F939, 0x05F93F, 0x06FA42, 0x05FA43, 0x05FA47, 0x04FB4B, 0x04FA4F, 0x04FA51, 0x05FA54, 0x04FA57, 0x04FA57, 0x04FA5B, 0x03FB5D, 0x03FA61, 0x03FA65, 0x04FA67, 0x04FA69, 0x04F96D, 0x04F96E, 0x04F970, 0x04F976, 0x04F97A, 0x05F980, 0x04F982, 0x04F984, 0x05F988, 0x07FB8A, 0x05FB8E, 0x03FA8F, 0x03FA92, 0x04FB93, 0x06FB96, 0x06FB96, 0x05FA9B, 0x05FA9F, 0x03FAA1, 0x04FAA5, 0x04F9A9, 0x04FBAC, 0x04FBAC, 0x04FBAC, 0x04FBB5, 0x04FBB7, 0x04FAB9, 0x04FABB, 0x04F8C2, 0x05F9C5, 0x03F9C6, 0x03F9C8, 0x04F9CE, 0x02F7CC, 0x05F7CF, 0x06F7D4, 0x03F6D8, 0x04F8DE, 0x05F8E4, 0x02F7E5, 0x03F8E7, 0x03F8E7, 0x03F8E9, 0x03F7ED, 0x04F7F1, 0x04F6F7, 0x04F6FA, 0x03F4FB, 0x05F1FF, 0x02EEFC, 0x05EEFD, 0x04E9FC, 0x05E8FB, 0x06E7FD,
                          0x04E1FB, 0x05E2FC, 0x06DDF9, 0x02D6FE, 0x01D5FA, 0x04D6F7, 0x04D1FE, 0x05CEF8, 0x06CBF6, 0x03C4FD, 0x05C2FC, 0x02BEFB, 0x03BCFC, 0x05BBFD, 0x04B5FB, 0x03B1FA, 0x04B0FC, 0x04AEFC, 0x02ABFC, 0x04ABFC, 0x03AAFB, 0x03A7FC, 0x04A4FC, 0x049FFC, 0x059BFC, 0x0498FC, 0x0592FE, 0x028FFB, 0x038BFB, 0x0389FC, 0x0586FD, 0x0482FB, 0x057FFC, 0x057FFE, 0x057CFE, 0x0277FB, 0x0474FC, 0x0671FD, 0x056BFC, 0x0468FC, 0x0468FE, 0x0466FF, 0x0361FE, 0x035BFB, 0x0659FD, 0x0354FB, 0x0354FD, 0x0654FE, 0x034FFA, 0x064EFA, 0x054AFD, 0x0446FC, 0x0343FC, 0x0442F9, 0x053FF8, 0x043BF7, 0x0338FA, 0x0536FF, 0x0734FF, 0x0530FB, 0x042DFB, 0x0528FC, 0x0223FA, 0x0521FE, 0x0720FF, 0x051DFD, 0x0517FD, 0x0415FB, 0x0412FB, 0x030FFB, 0x040DFC, 0x0509FE, 0x0406FB, 0x0203FB, 0x0201FC, 0x0402FD, 0x0601FD, 0x0600FE, 0x0302FD, 0x0402FD, 0x0801FC, 0x0B02FD, 0x0E02FA, 0x1502FC, 0x1A01FD, 0x1C01FC, 0x1C02FB, 0x2003FD, 0x2303FC, 0x2601FC, 0x2A01FB, 0x2B02FC, 0x2C02FC, 0x3001FD, 0x3201FB, 0x3801FC, 0x3A02FB, 0x3E03FD, 0x4202F9, 0x4601FC, 0x4A02FC, 0x4D02FD, 0x4D02FB, 0x4E02FA, 0x5202F7, 0x5501F7, 0x5B00FB, 0x5E02FB, 0x6303FB, 0x6502FB, 0x6701FA, 0x6802FB, 0x6B02FC, 0x6A01FC, 0x6C02FC, 0x7002FB, 0x7502FD, 0x7B02FD, 0x8002FC, 0x8401FC, 0x8602FD, 0x8902FE, 0x8D02FD, 0x8D02FD, 0x8F03FC, 0x9102FC, 0x9402FB, 0x9801FC, 0x9B02FB, 0x9E03FD, 0xA302FD, 0xA500FA, 0xAC03FE, 0xAC02FB, 0xAE01FB, 0xB203FC, 0xB500FB, 0xBC02FD, 0xBD00FC, 0xC001FE, 0xC403FE, 0xC502FC, 0xC602FA, 0xCA02FB, 0xCD02FA,
                          0xCD02FA, 0xD402FB, 0xD702FC, 0xD902FD, 0xDD02FC, 0xE102FB, 0xE402FC, 0xE802FB, 0xEC01FC, 0xED00FC, 0xF202F9, 0xF601FE, 0xF602F7, 0xF600FF, 0xF703F8, 0xFA02F9, 0xFD02F0, 0xFD02F0, 0xFD02F0, 0xFC01EE, 0xFC01EF, 0xFD03DF, 0xFC02E0, 0xFC02E0, 0xFC02DE, 0xFD03D9, 0xFC02D8, 0xFB03CD, 0xFD02CE, 0xFD02CD, 0xFD03C7, 0xFD01C6, 0xFC02BC, 0xFC02BE, 0xFB01BA, 0xFB02B4, 0xFD02B3, 0xFD02B3, 0xFC01B2, 0xFC02AE, 0xFC02AC, 0xFC01A8, 0xFC02A4, 0xFC02A1, 0xFC039F, 0xFC039F, 0xFB029E, 0xFC0298, 0xFB0294, 0xFC018F, 0xFC018E};

void AnimateRainbowBar(HDC hdc)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 498; i++)
  {
    SetPixel(hdc, 100 + i, 100, imageData[i]);
  }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  switch (msg)
  {
  case WM_PAINT:
  {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    AnimateRainbowBar(hdc);

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;
  }
  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
  default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
  }
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
  WNDCLASSEX wc = {sizeof(WNDCLASSEX)};
  wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
  wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
  wc.hInstance = hInstance;
  wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
  wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)); // Use window background color
  wc.lpszClassName = "RainbowBarWindow";
  RegisterClassEx(&wc);

  HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(0, "RainbowBarWindow", "Rainbow Bar", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                             100, 100, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

  ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

  MSG msg;
  while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
  {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }

  return (int)msg.wParam;
}


You can do this with a timer, something like this:

Call SetTimer(hwnd, 1, 2, NULL); right before calling ShowWindow. You timer will be triggered every 2 milliseconds.
Handle the WM_TIMER message where you cycle the colors and invalidate the Window so it gets redrawn
That's pretty much all

  case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;

  // Add this: (will be called automatically)
  case WM_TIMER:
    CycleColors();
    InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);  // invalidate Window so it will be redrawn automaticalle
    return 0;
    break;
  // end Add

  default:
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);

Then write a CycleColors() function that tweaks the imageData. I let you write this one.
Hint: use std::deque<int> for imageData instead of a raw C array, then the CycleColors() function can be trivially written in 3 lines.
Worry about efficiency later, indeed SetPixel is very slow as pointeds out by this answer:

thanks for the help i created the function that changes the array using deque. It works but it flickers ;(

Try handling WM_ERASEBKGD. See the comments about that in my answer.

SetPixel is really slow, and kinda useless for anything performant.
What you need to do, if you want straight-up GDI, is build your own buffer and do all your pixel operations direct in memory. That means you use CreateDIBitmap to build a HBITMAP object, supplying your image data as the buffer (in the appropriate pixel format).
Then, when you are drawing (e.g. when handling WM_PAINT or WM_ERASEBKGD), you need to create CreateCompatibleDC to create a new DC, select your bitmap object into that DC, and bit-blit (BitBlt) to copy your image data into the window's client area.
That does the whole image at once, as if you made many calls to SetPixel, but way faster.
e.g.
// Example variables that might hold your bitmap info
int nWidth = 498;
int nHeight = 1;
uint8_t pixelBuffer;   //<-- your image data (BGR-triples)
HBITMAP hBitmap;       //<-- result of CreateDIBitmap

// Example co-ordinate to draw at (top-left)
POINT target = { 100, 100 };

void AnimateRainbowBar(HDC hdc)
{
    // Draw my bitmap to buffer
    HDC hdcBitmap = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hBitmapOld = SelectBitmap(hdcBitmap, hBitmap);
    BitBlt(hdc, target.x, target.y, nWidth, nHeight, hdcBitmap, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // Cleanup Bitamap DC
    SelectBitmap(hdcBitmap, hBitmapOld);
    DeleteDC(hdcBitmap);
}

If you want to animate, then you need a timer that will regularly fire and either invalidate or directly paint your window. You can update your animation before painting. If you get flickering, the background might be an issue. You can handle WM_ERASEBKGD and ignore it.

That's somewhat advanced for a beginner, but yes, this is the correct approach.

Works well with your answer that covered the timer setup :) I did skip over how to correctly create the bitmap, but there's probably many examples on Stack Overflow

I'm curious why someone would want to do this in GDI rather than Direct2D.
